# Shift key not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, dell-latitude

The Shift keys on my laptop are not working, though it was fine until last night.

I'm running Windows 7 Professional 32-bit on a Dell Latitude e6410.

Comment: Have you tried a system restore to two days ago?

Comment: no. i haven't made any systems changes.

Comment: i have already uninstall/reinstall the keyboard dirver, still no luck. stick keys option is also turn off.

Comment: I mean for you to restore your system.

Comment: yah.. i will give it a try.

Comment: i restored to yesterday morning point,the only point i have. but still not working.

Comment: Do they work in Safe Mode?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a hardware issue, best thing to verify you do not have a hardware issue. Is to run the on-board diagnostics.

From a complete shutdown, press and Hold the [FN key] and the [Power button] at the same time. When lights start to come on, release both buttons.

Comment: Is this a Dell-specific key combination? I've never heard of it, so I'm very interested :)

Comment: I'd say a better way to verify would be to boot into another OS (from a live USB perhaps) and test the key there. "on-board diagnostics" are bound to be limited to only test certain things.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little late, but maybe helpful for others who come here - I had the same problem with an Acer Aspire VA70. I turned Sticky Keys on and off again, and now my shift keys are back to normal.